# Sinatra redirect to show params

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Im building a simple practice Sinatra app which allows users to enter urls via a form, and once submitted the app will open each of these urls in a new table (similar to [urlopener.com](http://urlopener.com))

My `app.rb` file

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
    erb :'index.html'
end

post '/' do
    urls = params[:urls]
end
```

My `View` file

```
<h1>Enter URLs Below </h1>
<form action="/" method="post">
<textarea rows="40" cols="50" id="urls" name="urls" ></textarea>
<br/>
<input type= "submit" value="Open 'em up!">
</form>
```

I am able to print the urls to the console in the `post action`, but am unsure how to redirect back to the `index`, and display each of the urls before opening them in new tabs (which I plan on using JS to do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to redirect back to the original page (in fact, the URL hasn't changed, so redirecting doesn't make sense). Instead, you render the **same template**. Simply insert `erb :'index.html'` in the second block (`post '/'`) as well, and put the URLs in a *class variable*, so that they will be available to the template:

```
@urls=params[:urls].split
```

(The `split` is there so you get an array of strings, rather than one long string with linebreaks.)

Finally, you add some logic to the template to check whether there are any URLs to display, and if so render them as a list:

```
<% if @urls && !@urls.empty? %>
  <h1>URLs</h1>
  <ul>
  <% for @url in @urls %>
    <li>
      <%= @url %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>

<h1>Enter URLs Below </h1> 
...etc...
```